# Error Message APK Not Installed In Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am new in Xamarin Forms, And I have created one sample application in vs 2017 community version 15.9.12, All works fine during dubbing and testing, and it run very fine on emulator. But the problem is after creating APK and trying to install it in other android devices its showing error message, "APK not installed", I have searched a lot, but not able to find any solution, let me share you images what i am trying to do.

**Setting Android Minimum And Maximum Version here**

[image]

**Setting Release Option As provided guide on internet**

[image]

**Archiving project**

[image]

**successfully created apk**

[image]

**Created Android Key Store**

[image]

**With save as option created apk and trying to open in other android device**

[image]

At last I am trying to install created apk in other android devices and its showing error message "APK Not Installed".
Can anyone help?

Thanks In Advance :)

Happy programming.

Comment: kindly check you Android CPU Architectures. armeabi and arm64-v8a must have checked while creating apk. please check once

Comment: Right click on the Project Properties Go to **Android Options>Advanced>Supported ABI's** Select all of them and then try making an APK

Comment: You should use logcat to check the error in that the phone is giving while installing. Android Device Monitor

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Signed the Android Application Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows), hava a try follow.

- Drop the SIGNED APK file onto your phone
- Install using the SIGNED APK file
- When installing, a PLAY STORE prompt will appear...choose "Install Anyway"